# Angular 10 + NodeJS + Express - Can't get Image to load but works locally

Tags: node.js, angular, express, production-environment

## The Problem

I have a Angular project that i've deployed onto a Linux Server + NodeJS + Express.
When I run the project locally - all of the images load fine.
When I upload the project onto the server and visit the site, it will not load the static images.

## My Folder Structure

```
Project
- dist (Angular DIST Folder)
    - assets
        - images
            - logo.png
    - index.html
    - styles.css
    - etc
- config
- controllers
- node_modules
- routes
- templates
- package.json
- server.js
```

## Server.js

Here is the code for my server.js file:

```
// imports
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

// Parsers
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}));

// Angular DIST output folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

require("./routes/api.routes")(app);

// Send all other requests to the Angular app
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});

// set port, listen for requests
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
});
```

Hoping someone could help me out!

Comment: Did you try hitting the absolute URL path to the server directly and see if the image was loaded?

Comment: The absolute path does not work either.

Comment: You’re sending every request that is not an API route to index.html..

Comment: Should that be just app instead of app/index.html?

Comment: I can confirm that your configuration works locally, also in a docker container. How do you configure the remote server? Does it allow access to /assets? You could check in the server log of express if the express server even receives the request to /assets.

Comment: @code-gorilla could you share your Dockerfile? i'd love to try and get this working through a Docker container

Comment: I tested in in the command line without a docker file:
Start node container: `docker run -v $(pwd):/app -p 3000:3000 -it /bin/bash`
In node container run: `cd /app && npm start`